# Prove that normal cone of a closed convex set is different from the set has only element 0

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-cone

> **Problem:** Suppose that $E$ is Euclidean space. Given a closed convex set $C \subset E,$ the **normal
> cone** $N_C$ to $C$ at $x \in C$ is defined by $$N_C(x) := \left\{v \in
>  E^{*}:\forall y \in C, \langle v,y-x \rangle \le 0 \right\}.$$ Prove
> that $N_C(x) \neq \left\{0\right\}$ for any $x \in \text{bd}(C)$ (the
> boundary of $C$).

My direction: I try to point out there is a point in $N_C(x)$ that is different from $0$. But I don't know how to use the assumption $x \in \text{bd}(C)$.

Comment: I would like to point out that the result is no longer true if $E$ is an *infinite-dimensional* Hilbert space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $q \in E \setminus C$ define $P(q) = \text{argmin}_{x \in C}\lVert q - x \rVert$. An argmin exists since $C$ is closed, and the argmin is unique since $C$ is convex. It is a basic result that for every $q \in E \setminus C$, $q - P(q) \in N_C(P(q))$. To prove this you can translate coordinates so that $P(q) = 0$, then rotate coordinates so that $q$ is a multiple of $e_n$, and then prove the result by contradiction.

Since $x \in bC = b(E \setminus C)$, there exists a sequence $(q_n)$ in $E \setminus C$ such that $(q_n) \to x$. Set $x_n = P(q_n)$. Since $(q_n) \to x$, we have $\lVert q_n - x_n \rVert = d(q_n, C) \to d(x, C) = 0$. It follows that $(x_n) \to x$ also. Let $v_n = \frac{q_n - x_n}{\lVert q_n - x_n \rVert}$. Note that $v_n \in N_C(x_n)$. Also note that $(v_n)$ is a sequence in the unit sphere, a compact set. Thus passing to a subsequence, we can assume $(v_n) \to v$ for some $v$ in the unit sphere. I leave it to you to show that $v \in N_C(x)$.